# Curly braces with subscript and superscript

Tags: brackets, subscripts, superscripts

I'm looking for a way to write something like this:

```
\lbrace A_i\rbrace _{i = 1}^{n}
```

My goal is to put a subscript and a superscript near the right curly brace. How can I do it? The subscript and the superscript should be below and above the ends of the right curly brace.

Comment: You could use some sort of `\strut`.  `\lbrace A_i\rbrace \rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}_{i = 1}^{n}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The subscript and the superscript should be below and [above] the ends of the right curly brace.

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\overunderset" macro
\begin{document}
$
\overunderset{n}{i=1}{\rbrace}     \quad
\overunderset{n}{i=1}{\big\rbrace} \quad
\overunderset{n}{i=1}{\Big\rbrace} \quad
\overunderset{n}{i=1}{\bigg\rbrace}\quad
\overunderset{n}{i=1}{\Bigg\rbrace}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Mico thank you very much for your great answer.

Answer (score 8):

Using another approach with `\mathop`,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathop{\}}\limits_{i=1}^{n}$,
$\mathop{\bigr\}}\limits_{i=1}^{n}$,
$\mathop{\biggr\}}\limits_{i=1}^{n}$,
$\mathop{\Bigr\}}\limits_{i=1}^{n}$,
$\mathop{\Biggr\}}\limits_{i=1}^{n}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Sebastiano I appreciate your contributiom.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Holà..I am glady to help you...my regards from Sicily.

Answer (score 8):

One needs to declare the object as a closing delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rbracex}{O{}e{^_}}{%
  \mathclose{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% #2 is the possible superscript
      \underset{#2}{#1\rbrace}%
    }{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}{% #3 is the possible subscript
        \overset{#2}{#1\rbrace}%
      }{%
        \overunderset{#2}{#3}{#1\rbrace}%
      }%
    }%
  }% matching \mathclose
}

\begin{document}

\[
\lbrace A\rbracex_{i=1}^n
\quad
\big\lbrace A\rbracex[\big]_{i=1}^n
\quad
\Big\lbrace A\rbracex[\Big]_{i=1}^n
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid this notation with great care.

A possible improvement, prompted by comments by barbara beeton:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rbracex}{O{}e{^_}}{%
  \mathclose{%
    % let's compute the amount of backing up
    \sbox0{\mathsurround=0pt$#1\rbrace$}%
    \sbox2{\mathsurround=0pt
      $\IfNoValueTF{#2}{% #2 is the possible superscript
        \underset{#2}{#1\rbrace}%
      }{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#3}{% #3 is the possible subscript
          \overset{#2}{#1\rbrace}%
        }{%
          \overunderset{#2}{#3}{#1\rbrace}%
        }%
      }$%
    }% end of \sbox2
   \ifdim\wd0>\wd2
     % do nothing
   \else
     \kern\dimexpr(\wd0-\wd2)/2\relax
   \fi
   \usebox{2}%
  }% matching \mathclose
}

\begin{document}

\[
\lbrace A_i\rbracex_{i=1}^n
\quad
\big\lbrace A_i\rbracex[\big]_{i=1}^n
\quad
\Big\lbrace A_i\rbracex[\Big]_{i=1}^n
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Well, not really an improvement, I'm afraid.

Comment: The width of the "lower limit" makes what's inside the braces look off center (which, of course, it is), and the shape of the *A* makes that look even worse.  I'm not qualified to say whether there's a compelling mathematical reason for this, but I can't believe that closing up that space to match the space on the left would change the meaning.  (Maybe just ignore the width of the lower limit.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's maybe possible to measure the objects and back up; but what if the thing inside is `A_n`? Clash would be unavoidable. Anyway, I can't see any compelling reason and actually see a few reasons for not going along with this. The main reason being that the sub/superscripts don't belong to the brace, but to the whole `{...}` thing. Perhaps I'm influenced by not being a fan of `\{a_n\}_{i=1}^n` to begin with.

Comment: @barbarabeeton See [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tft9I.png)

Comment: With the subscript, that looks much more balanced.  But the space on the right looks smaller, and I think it's not entirely the fact that something has been added.  If I measured the spaces at the baseline, I think the right-hand space after the subscript is a bit narrower than the space with no subscript.  Is it all my imagination, or did you make an adjustment?

Comment: @barbarabeeton It was just a cheap experiment, with the backing up measured “by sight”, to show that the output is not really that nice.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added the backing up; I'm afraid this is even worse than the original.